# GitHub pages link returns blank page for React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, npm, web-hosting

I've tried the following:

1. Added homepage to package.json
2. npm install gh-pages --save-dev
3. npm run deploy

When I ran "npm run deploy" it returned the following message:

```
$ npm run deploy

> myportfoliosite@0.1.0 predeploy C:\Users\Ar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\myportfoliosite\myportfoliosite
> npm run build


> myportfoliosite@0.1.0 build C:\Users\Ar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\myportfoliosite\myportfoliosite
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

./src/App.js
  Line 3:  'download' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

File sizes after gzip:

  73.02 KB  build\static\js\2.f6e5e996.chunk.js
  19.04 KB  build\static\css\2.b1979bb4.chunk.css
  797 B     build\static\js\runtime~main.4f085a03.js
  152 B     build\static\js\main.a0a932a3.chunk.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /InquisitiveDev2016/ReactDeveloperPortfolio/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:
```

I turned on GitHub pages for the "gh pages branch" and it gave me a website link @ https://github.com/InquisitiveDev2016/ReactDeveloperPortfolio

However, the link is returning a blank page.(It did show the Readme section before but now it is completely blank).

I'm not sure why it is not giving me a link that displays my react app.

Comment: Did you enable github pages for the repository?

Comment: The GH-Pages link is https://inquisitivedev2016.github.io/ReactDeveloperPortfolio/index.html

Comment: @IvanRubinson Yes I enabled it through the settings option. The link you gave me is still returning a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

The homepage field in `package.json` is supposed to point to the URL at which you are hosting the github page.

In this case, that is: https://inquisitivedev2016.github.io/ReactDeveloperPortfolio/

[Docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson)

Currently it points to the github repository

Comment: It's still a blank page though. Look in the console, you can see some errors.

Comment: might just be cache, try Shift+Refreshing the page

Comment: Thanks that helped! Is there a way to access the landingpage.js(homepage)? Right now I have https://inquisitivedev2016.github.io/ReactDeveloperPortfolio/  but I would like for it to go to the homepage. I have tried https://inquisitivedev2016.github.io/src/components/landingpage but it is returning a 404 error

Comment: @DreamVision2017 Currently gh-pages does not have routing support, but there are some [workarounds](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#notes-on-client-side-routing) listed in the docs itself

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming u have added the following lines in your package.json file

```
"homepage":"https://{Your_Github_Username}.github.io/{repo-name}", //outside dependencies

"scripts": {
    .
    .
    "predeploy":"npm run build",
    "deploy":"gh-pages -d build"
}
```

I was able to fix the issue after I saw the error in the console. In my case the error was with the https request. I had added a script link in index.html with 'http' when I changed it to 'https' it worked perfectly fine.

And don't forget to commit and push the changes after you have found the error and run deploy again..